# fql.get method return empty Array in Facebook Application with facebook-php-sdk-v2.1.2-4

Tags: facebook

Recently I am trying to develop a facebook application that shows the STATUSES of loged in facebook user.
I am succeeded to retrieve information from user table using FQL. But right now I am using this following code to get data from status table.

*******BEGIN :: CODE SECTION************************

$sql    =   "SELECT message,time FROM status WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = ".$myLoginId.")";

$param  =   array(
//        'method'    => 'fql.query',
        'method'    => 'status.get',
                'query'     => $sql,
                'callback'  => ''
            );
            $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

```
    print_r($fqlResult);
```

****END:: CODE SECTION*****************

But everytimes it returns Empty Array.
Right Now I am using Library of facebook-php-sdk-v2.1.2-4-g2343fca.tar which I collect from github.com.

can anybody please give me a solution.
Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You code is working just fine, just a small note, you can use `me()` to get the current user id:

```
$fql = "SELECT uid,message,time FROM status WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
$fqlResult = $this->facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => $fql
));
```

AND once again, the most important part is acquiring the correct [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), which are `user_status` (if you want to get your statuses) ***AND*** `friends_status` (to get your friends' statuses).